# No such directory: C:/Users/Admin/IdeaProjects/untitled/src/com/company/Main.java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write my first Java program, but I'm getting this error trying to open the main.java terminal:

> Cannot open Local Terminal
>
> No such directory: C:/Users/Admin/IdeaProjects/untitled/src/com/company/Main.java
>
> Error running process: CreateProcess failed. Code 267
>  
> See IDE log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you see the IDE log for the details?

Comment: Please update your title to just describe the actual problem or question.

Comment: May be helpful to include the code line or section that results in the error.

Comment: @hemoo you should put the code you wrote in your answer, so people can help you fix the problem

Comment: @kayaman No, I'll look at it now.

Comment: @user306038 It's not an error because of my code, I have not wrote any code till now, I'm just trying to open the terminal of my main.java.

Comment: But what is the terminal of `main.java`?
Can you include a screenshot of what the terminal looks like or something like that?

Comment: Well, `Main.java` is not a directory, it's a file. It's also unclear what you mean by "open the terminal of my main.java". Why are you trying to open the terminal? What does your `Main.java` contain?

Comment: @Kayaman in a comment above, hemoo says he didn't write any code. Maybe that's why it gives him an error. My theory:  (There's nothing inside `Main.java`)

Comment: @user306038 Sorry if I look dumb, I'm just new to programming. Anyways, First of all I'm using Intellij, and when I right click on the file Main.java, there is an option that appears named, open and then 3 more choices appear, one of them is open in terminal and when I press on it, the error I posted up appears.

Comment: @hemoo Look at Atmas's answer. Try that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are just getting started my best advice to you is to search for a step by step guide on how to do what you're doing that is specific to your specific IDE.

Here is one example guide to starting Java from that IDE: https://www.javatpoint.com/intellij-idea-first-java-program

Comment: I think this the answer @hemoo is looking for. 

Comment: I hope so too. Seems like they are a little lost. But we all have to start somewhere so no judgment.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, you are so nice and kind. Yeah I'm kind of lost and some people here going hard on me. I'll do what you said and if you have any advice for me as beginner programmer, I'll take. Have a nice day bro.

Comment: Just a couple noteworthy things. The going hard part is because you're at SO asking for beginner's help on how to do something. This is just the wrong place for that. There are numerous sources online to help you. It's just sort of a "wrong tool for the job" situation. For more formal understanding of "what is right", check these links out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and als https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, you should click to accept answer for the answer that best meets the question, so feel free to do that here if you're happy with mine and I'll get some kudos points for getting you going in the right direction.